# running a java program - without much technical knowledge

Tags: java, batch-file, usability

I create many ad-hoc java programs for "business users" to use. These programs often take input as command line parameters.

To make it easy for them to run these programs, I create a batch file for each program which has entire java command to run it along with input parameters.

I am asking them to update these input parameters, save file, double click file to run program for different set of input. However they're finding it difficult and not very comfortable with this approach.

I don't want to create n batch files for them for n inputs and also we don't know all inputs which may come in future.

I was wondering if is there any standard solution to this issue? May be a GUI already available or anything which can ease their life?

Thanks.

Comment: What about a shell script? Is it hard, too? `./batchManager.sh <program> [input parameters]`

Comment: how about batch file if you are on windows ? or if you want generic, then perl scipt and others?

Comment: Some kind of GUI program that lets you view and edit a file containing text? I think such things exist.

Comment: Why don't you create a GUI that allows users to changes settings, then launches the jar with its input parameters? You'd only have to create the class once, then use it as the main class of any jar users run.

Comment: Thanks but all shell/perl script suggestions are no different than what I have (batch) at the moment.

Comment: I considered creating custom GUI - but asked here if there is any standard solution already available?

Comment: You can make the batchfile ask for the params. Or you could put that part into the java prog. Another approach would be a property file or config file or you could use a gui. What kind of params are those?

Comment: In windows consider using taskscheduler.exe which is free and built in Create basic task, one time, start a program, they put the parameters here. If they want to rerun or schedule it it will be stored in their scheduler for later use

Answer (score 0):

If you can and want to add a method such as this to each of your programs' main class:

```
public static String[] usage(){
    return new String[]{
        "name", "\\w+",
        "number", "\\d+" };
}
```

then this Wrapper class can provide a generic prompt for invoking the program with (more or less) correct arguments:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        System.out.println( args.getClass() );
        Class<?> prog = Class.forName( args[0] );
        Method mu = prog.getMethod( "usage" );
        String[] nps = (String[])mu.invoke( null );
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
        List<String> pars = new ArrayList<>();
        for( int i = 0; i < nps.length; i += 2 ){
            boolean ok = false;
            while( ! ok ){
                System.out.print( nps[i] + ": " );
                String line = scan.nextLine().trim();
                if( line.matches( nps[i+1] ) ){
                    ok = true;
                    pars.add( line );
                } else {
                    System.err.println( "input error - please retry" );
                }
            }
        }
        String[] params = pars.toArray( new String[pars.size()] );
        Method mm = prog.getMethod( "main", args.getClass() );
        mm.invoke( null, (Object)(params) );
    }
}
```

The Wrapper has to be invoked with the name of the class containing the (hitherto) primary main method. Except for the addition of usage, existing code doesn't have to be changed.

NB: Some exception handling needs to be added, e.g. when Class.forName throws an exception ClassNotFoundException.